# Filtro dinamico en php, con sql sin plugins

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una pequeña pregunta, que no he podido resolver. Lo que sucede, es que quiero hacer un filtro dinamico en php, que aplique los filtros a traves de una lista desplegable, solo si se los indico. Es decir, de los tres posibles filtros, aplique uno si solo le indico uno, aplique dos si le ingreso 2 filtros y asi (considerar que estos 3 filtros son listas desplegables).

Actualmente el codigo que genera el filtro es este:

```
                     <?php
$dev_name = $_POST['dev_name'];
$stdev_location_name = $_POST['stdev_location_name'];
$dev_serial = $_POST['dev_serial'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM stdevice
          JOIN stlocation ON stdevice.ubicacion = stlocation.stdev_id
          JOIN device_name ON stdevice.dev_id = device_name.dev_id
          WHERE 1";

$conditions = array();

if (!empty($dev_name)) {
    $conditions[] = "dev_name LIKE '%$dev_name%'";
}

if (!empty($stdev_location_name)) {
    $conditions[] = "stdev_location_name LIKE '%$stdev_location_name%'";
}

if (!empty($dev_serial)) {
    $conditions[] = "dev_serial LIKE '%$dev_serial'";
}

if (!empty($conditions)) {
    $query .= " AND (" . implode(" OR ", $conditions) . ")";
}

$count_item = mysqli_query($query);

if ($count_item === false) {
    die("Error en la consulta: " . mysqli_error());
}

$count = mysqli_num_rows($count_item);
?>
```

Este codigo funciona si le indico el primero y dejo los otros dos en blanco, pero si ingreso el segundo filtro, deja de funcionar (mostrando todos los datos, como si no hubiese indicado ningun filtro). Hay algo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Has depurado en tu DBM el resultado de `$query` ??

Comment: Seguro que las condiciones las unes con OR y no AND ?

Comment: No parece haber un problema en la construcción de la consulta. Verifica que esté llegando correctamente esta variable: `$_POST['stdev_location_name']` desde el formulario. Puedes imprimir un `echo $query;` y pega ese resultado directo en el manejador de BD a ver si sucede lo mismo.